# Setting up ruby-rvm (1.6.9-0ubuntu2) ... error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
Setting up ruby-rvm (1.6.9-0ubuntu2) ...
dpkg-statoverride: error: syntax error: unknown group 'admin' in statoverride file
dpkg: error processing ruby-rvm (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
ruby-rvm
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This error is drivin me crazy. can anyone help me.. m fed offfffff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ruby-rvm/+bug/963662

```
Locate /var/lib/dpkg/info/ruby-rvm.postinst
```

Opened it and replaced the admin group requirement to sudo. Save the file and try again.